# C++ - ‘_itoa’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

In the UserProfile.h, I declared the class UserProfile...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class UserProfile
{
   ...
}
```

then, I defined the function UserProfile() and operator<< in the UserProfile.cpp

```
#include "UserProfile.h"
#include <cstdlib>

inline UserProfile::UserProfile()
    : _login("guest"), _user_level(Beginner),
      _times_logged(1), _guesses(0), _correct_guesses(0)
{
    static int id = 0;
    char buffer[16];

    _itoa(id++, buffer, 10);
    _login += buffer;
}
...
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const UserProfile &rhs)
{
    os << rhs.login() << ' '
       << rhs.level() << ' '
       << rhs.login_count() << ' '
       << rhs.guess_count() << ' '
       << rhs.guess_correct() << ' '
       << rhs.guess_average() << endl;
    return os;
}
```

However, when I try to compile them, the g++ report error:

```
g++ UserProfile.cpp E44.cpp -o main
UserProfile.cpp: In constructor ‘UserProfile::UserProfile()’:
UserProfile.cpp:11:27: error: ‘_itoa’ was not declared in this scope
     _itoa(id++, buffer, 10);
```

But I have included "cstdlib"... so strange...

Also, when I want to use << in my main cpp, the g++ report error too:

```
#include "UserProfile.h"

int main()
{
    UserProfile anon;
    cout << anon;
    ...
}
```

g++ report:

```
E44.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:


E44.cpp:6:10: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘UserProfile’)
    cout << anon;
```

I am so confused... Did I do something wrong??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct name of the function is **itoa** not **_itoa**. However, it cannot be used in C++. *cplusplus.com* says:

> This function is not defined in ANSI-C and is not part of C++, but is supported by some compilers.

Instead, use std::to_string or string streams.

As far as the compile time error regarding operator<< is concerned, that is because you define the operator in another translation unit than the one with the **main** function which will be compiled separately I guess and you don't **declare** it in the header file. In order for this to work you need to declare the overloaded operator, preferably in the same header file as the class' header file **UserProfile.h**.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const UserProfile &rhs);
```

Moreover, you may want to make it a **friend** of your class to directly access fields and not using methods. That doesn't break encapsulation because you implement both the class and the overloaded operator.

```
class UserProfile
{
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const UserProfile &rhs);
};
```

Comment: Thank you! After adding the declaration in the UserProfile.h, the problem of operator<< is solved indeed. However, even I use the function itoa, the g++ still report error: ‘itoa’ was not declared in this scope, also, I just googled the itoa and _itoa. It seems that _itoa is legal also.:)